# select two logins from one record

Tags: mysql, select, join, union

I'm creating chat ( just for two people to chat, not "global" ) and my tables look like this:

**MESSAGES:**

```
id | author | receiver | content | sent
```

where author and receiver are id's from **USERS**:

```
id | login | avatar
```

and i want to get login and avatar both from receiver and author of the message. I was trying with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
((SELECT messages.*,users.login as starter,users.avatar FROM messages
    LEFT JOIN users ON messages.author = users.id
    WHERE messages.receiver = 1)
UNION 
(SELECT messages.*,users.login as test,users.avatar FROM messages
    LEFT JOIN users ON messages.receiver = users.id
    WHERE messages.author = 1)
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) tmp 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

and few other queries but i could only get one login ( either receiver or author ). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: U are using the same id (e.g. 1) for either receiver and author -> u're getting only one login, since is about one and the same user. Guessing they should be different...

Comment: but than i get two results from one record in database..

Comment: Double-join the `USERS` table

Comment: @geomagas emm how to?:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from messages m
join users a on (m.author=a.id)
join users r on (m.reciever=r.id)
```

Of course, you can add a `where` clause to filter it for a specific message, author or whatever.

Comment: Or whatever. How about using a column list?